# Show that for any $x,y \in X$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\left<x,e_k\right>\left<y,e_k\right>|\le \|x\|\|y\|.$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthonormal

> Let $(e_k)$ be any orthonormal sequence in an inner product space $X$. Show that for any $x,y \in X$ $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\left<x,e_k\right>\left<y,e_k\right>|\le \|x\|\|y\|.$$

If $x=y$, then the proof becomes trivial, as then the result follows directly from [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\left<x,e_k\right>|^2\le \|x\|^2.$$

Now suppose that $x \neq y$, then \begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\left<x,e_k\right>\left<y,e_k\right>| &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\left<\left<x,e_k\right>y,e_k\right>\right|\end{align}
But I have no idea where to continue from here. Can anyone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a different route. What says Cauchy-Schwarz about it?

Comment: You actually manually added a small space between $||x||$ and $||y||$.  But if you had written $\|x\|\|y\|$, coded as \|x\|\|y\|, you would have found that proper spacing is built in to the software --- you just have to use it in the right way. (And besides, $||x||$ looks different from $\|x\|$.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy - Thanks, I'll remember that for future use :)

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y$, then Bessel's inequality applies directly, as written in the OP.

For $x\neq y\,$ an preliminary step using the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality yields the result
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\big|\langle x| e_k\rangle\langle y| e_k\rangle\big|
 \;\leqslant\;
 \left(\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^\infty\big|\langle x| e_k\rangle\big|^2\right)^{1/2}\;
\left(\sum_{k=1}\nolimits^\infty\big|\langle y|e_k\rangle\big|^2\right)^{1/2}
 \;\leqslant\; \|x\|\|y\|\,.$$